# How to connect Go API to Cassandra DB

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, cassandra, gocql

I'm using a Go API and I need to connect it to my Cassandra DB on a Google Cloud server.

This is my Go connection code:

```
func SetupDBConnection() {
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("XX.XXX.XXX.XXX")
    cluster.Keyspace = "afterstr"
    cluster.Consistency = gocql.Quorum

    s, err := cluster.CreateSession()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

But, when I run this code, I have this error:

*gocql: unable to create session: control: unable to connect to initial hosts: dial tcp xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9042: i/o timeout*

This is my Google Cloud configuration:

[image: server config]

[image: server config]

[image: server config]

I also modified the cassandra.yaml file in my server to change the listen address and the RPC address to put my IP with the port I use to run my Go program that I opened.
(It is opened 3 times because I was just testing something)

[image: opened ports]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cluster.Authenticator = gocql.PasswordAuthenticator{Username: username, Password: password}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but I don't know the user or the password.  Do you have any idea what to enter?

Comment: Try cassandra:cassandra it is default settings and I found this docs. Hope it will help https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/hybrid/v1.3/cassandra-tls